# Vimscript function range only applying to the first line

Tags: function, vim

I'm experimenting with creating my own commenting function, for vimscript learning purposes.

I've did the following:

```
function! Comment() range
  for line_number in range(a:firstline, a:lastline)
    let current_line = getline(line_number)
    let current_line_commented = substitute(current_line, '^', '# ', "")
    call setline(line_number, current_line_commented)
  endfor
endfunction

command! -range Comment call Comment()
```

However when calling the command with a given range (`:'<,'>Comment`) only the first line of the selection gets the `#` added in front, and no other errors are reported.

What am I missing to get every line from the range substituted?

Comment: I've tried your code, and it does gives error, as `linenum` doesn't exists -- you probably renamed it on the first line of the for and forgot to update the other references.

Comment: @mMontu That was probably an error while copying the function to stack overflow. Fixing now, it's OK on my vimrc.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Unlike a mapping (that when invoked in visual mode automatically gets the `:'<,'>` prepended to the function `:call`), a custom command needs to be passed the range explicitly:

```
command! -range Comment <line1>,<line2>call Comment()
```

`:help :command-range` unfortunately only mentions the related `<count>`, but you'll find the information further down at `:help <line1>.`

Comment: @mMontu: With your great preparation of commenting on the syntax error, I was able to just breeze through...

Comment: Dang... I wish I had found this post earlier -- would have saved me a boatload of time! It was only when I started to ask the question that it came up. Nice!